# Bootstrap 5 - justifty-content-end is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a header using bootstrap 5. Within the header I have a navbar with links that I would like to float to the right. After looking on the bootstrap website I noticed that they added a justifty-content-end class to their menu list items. When I do this the items stay to the left. I have even tried adding float: right to the nav but this doesn't work either.

Here is my html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
      <ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="myNavbar">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My css

```css
ul {
float: right !important:
}
```

Can someone please explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution, I have tried in my machine, this code working properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex justify-content-end">
        <!-- Navbar content -->
            <ul class="nav" id="myNavbar">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Hii Becky checks the code. I have updated my code recently

Comment: still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: it may work there but your code is not working for me, this might be because you have linked bootstrap 4 and I am using bootstrap 5

Comment: it's pretty much the same as your code in your answer, only it is linked to bootstrap 5 rather than bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It didn't matter where I applied justify-content-end, that is, to the nav element or the ul, it would never work.

I finally found something that worked: I placed the "ms-auto" class in my ul for the nav bar. This switched the default margin (m) placement (e = end) to the left of the nav items (s = start) - for Right-To-Left writing.

Here's something that worked for me:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
<!-- Navbar content -->
<ul class="nav ms-auto" id="myNavbar">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Worth noting that in Bootstrap 4 those classes used ml (margin left) and mr (margin right) and got switched in Bootstrap 5 to ms (margin start) and me (margin end) to be agnostic to RTL and LTR writers, which to me made it more difficult to find an answer to this question myself, since there's so many of them with references to ml and mr. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-end">
    <ul class="nav" id="myNavbar">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the width of the navbar is not 100% of the page. Even if you set the float of the content of the navbar, it changes only in the navbar.

You can try to set the float of the navbar to the right.

Or set the width of your navbar to 100% and add float:right to the content as below.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="background-color:green;width:100%;height:100px;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
      <ul class="nav justify-content-end" style="float:right;" id="myNavbar">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sadly doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Can you give more details pls ? Or can you post an image of expected result ?

Comment: I want my list items to float to the right of the navbar itself

Comment: I modified my answer, is that what you need ?

Comment: I want the ul items to float to the right

Comment: That is what actually I did. Check the response.

Comment: that doesn't seem to change anything